# Installing editline Library from source

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I'm using Ubuntu on WSL to build a software project. I need to install a library using a [tarball](https://github.com/troglobit/editline/archive/1.16.1.tar.gz) I've downloaded. Specifically, it's the command line editing library [editline](https://github.com/troglobit/editline).

So far I've unzipped the source code. The issue is with calling the `.\configure.ac` command. I'm getting the error:

```bsh
./configure.ac: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `editline,'
./configure.ac: line 1: `AC_INIT(editline, 1.16.1, https://github.com/troglobit/editline/issues)'
```

I've looked at the config file [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Initializing-configure.html) and it seems to be valid syntax. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The command is `./configure` not `./configure.ac`

Comment: @user.dz in the case of editline, they use autoconf it seems, so you'd have to do `./autogen.sh` first...

Comment: You're right @vidarlo. It seems they left out that step in the installation instructions. I'm doing that right now.

Comment: @vidarlo, you are right, i missed that. It is an autotools project. You may but it as an answer, seems to me that was the only missing piece for current state of question

Comment: @NewtonMigosi I suggest you self-answer the question with what you found out :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler process than extracting the tarball and manually installing dependencies like autoconf and libtool. I found that you can simply do `sudo apt install libedit-dev` which will fetch all the required files. In my case I also had to run the `sudo apt upgrade` command before running the installation command. This worked for me just fine and got my code running.